# In Android, does File.renameTo overwrite target file?

Tags: android, file

Even I can make a test I'd like to know if I can relay on all Androids to overwrite target file when renaming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to make sure the target file does not exist, otherwise it will return false.

Comment: Is this documented? Because the Oracle Java documentation says the behavior of this method depends on the platform, and the Android API page at https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File) doesn't say anything about this point as far as I can tell.

Comment: This is wrong. Files are overwritten since Android uses the normal Linux rename() syscall (see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html).

Comment: In my experience its don't allow rename. Please give a snippet otherwise.